# How to use the np.where function together with the index of each element of the array?

Tags: numpy

```
cashflow = [0] + [10] * 7
# [0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

for index in range(len(cashflow)):
    growth_cashflow = 1.05**index * cashflow[index]
```

or

```
growth_cashflow = [1.05**index*pmt[index] for index in range(len(pmt))]
```

the result is:

```
[10.0, 10.5, 11.025, 11.576250000000002, 12.155062500000003, 12.762815625000004, 13.400956406250003]
```

But is it possible to get the same result with `np.where`?

```
cf = np.array(cashflow)
s = np.where(cf >= 0, 1.05**cf.index*cf, cf)

ERROR => AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Is it possible to get the index of each item and use it in the above multiplication?

If not, is there another way to do numpy without using `for`?

Comment: You have a first element of 0 initially, but for the rest of the post the array is just the seven 10s.

Comment: `np.arange(6)` generates all values of `range(6)` at once.  `where` is not an iterator.  It's a python function, so its arguments are evaluated and then passed in.  They must be valid arrays, frames/series, or scalars..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
cf=np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
s = cf*1.05**np.arange(len(cf))
print(s)
```

This should give you the output you are looking for. If you really want to get specific indices, you may want to use `np.nonzero` or `np.argwhere`.